# Invalidating Http Session on maximum allowable session for a user

Tags: spring, session

I developed a web application using spring and hibernate. By using Spring Security , i am restricting one session per user. When user try to attempt multiple login then old session will be invalidated and new one will be active.I have registered HttpSessionListener in my web.xml file.In sessionDistroyed method i am writing some functionality that will be executed when Http Session getting invalidating.

Now problem is  when a single user try to do multiple login ,spring security expiring the old session but  not invalidating the old session.So in that case  sessionDistroyed method not being executed.But i want sessionDistroyed method to be called when spring security expiring the old session.

Can anyone please help to resolve this problem.

Comment: Hope you are using invalidate-session="true"

Comment: Yes I have set invalidate-session="true" in spring-security.xml file.